# How to get selected values from a table row in a table layout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am having table layout with twelve table rows and having 12 check boxes that is one in each row. I want to retrieve the selected check box row values even if I had select multiple check boxes also  this is what I had done but wont work for me please help me

```
package com.developer.android;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.material.widget.CheckBox;

public class Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt extends Fragment {

    public int []check_box_count = new int[12];
    public int [] Table_Row_Count = new int[12];
    TableRow table_row;
    TableLayout table;
    CheckBox check_box;
    int i;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);

        Table_Row_Count[0] = R.id.tableRow1_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[1] = R.id.tableRow2_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[2] = R.id.tableRow3_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[3] = R.id.tableRow4_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[4] = R.id.tableRow5_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[5] = R.id.tableRow6_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[6] = R.id.tableRow7_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[7] = R.id.tableRow8_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[8] = R.id.tableRow9_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[9] = R.id.tableRow10_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[10] = R.id.tableRow11_manual;
        Table_Row_Count[11] = R.id.Table_Row_12;

        table_row = (TableRow)Root_view.findViewById(Table_Row_Count[i]);

        check_box_count[0] = R.id.cb_1;
        check_box_count[1] = R.id.cb_2;
        check_box_count[2] = R.id.cb_3;
        check_box_count[3] = R.id.cb_4;
        check_box_count[4] = R.id.cb_5;
        check_box_count[5] = R.id.cb_6;
        check_box_count[6] = R.id.cb_7;
        check_box_count[7] = R.id.cb_8;
        check_box_count[8] = R.id.cb_9;
        check_box_count[9] = R.id.cb_10;
        check_box_count[10] = R.id.cb_11;
        check_box_count[11] = R.id.cb_12;
        check_box = (CheckBox)Root_view.findViewById(check_box_count[i]);

        registerForContextMenu(table_row);
        table_row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                for(int i=0;i<check_box.length();i++){
                if(check_box.isChecked()==true){
                    int count = table_row.getChildCount();
                    String[] str = new String[count];
                    for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
                        TextView tv = (TextView)(((TableRow)table_row)).getChildAt(i);
                        str[j] = tv.getText().toString();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Arrays.toString(str), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });



        return Root_view;


    }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a custom listview?

Comment: this code is done by listview so please if possible then use listview for this solution

Comment: No dude i want it with the table layout because here i had multiple columns and I want the dividers for each column because for that i placed the table layout

Comment: you asked the same exact thing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051134/how-to-get-selected-values-in-table-row-in-android